# Can't get dynamicType of a closure?

Tags: ios, swift

This code crashes my XCode playground every time.

```
var c : () -> () = {}
var cType = c.dynamicType
```

Does this happen for anyone else?

I've submitted a bug report (#17599940) to Apple already.

Comment: I did not downvote but we can't solve Xcode crash for you

Comment: however, `println(c.dynamicType)` seems to work fine; it's just assigning it to a variable that crashes the compiler

Comment: Fixed in Xcode 6.3.2 (6D2105), maybe earlier.